# Trying to right-align a pop-up element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to align pop-up elements in a header element in a table. Eventually the pop-up elements will provide functionality like sorting and filtering for my table.

Per default the pop ups align themselves to the ***left***, but I would like to align them to the ***right*** :

[image]

My CSS code looks like something like this :

```
.Table .Popup {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

I would like to use the **relative** position instead of **absolute** (ie.relative to the header item), but I am not sure how. If I use absolute, doesn't that interfere with any other parent containers that have position set to absolute?

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XJXuR/9/

Does anyone know how this can be done? JQuery or Javascript is fine. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Vf2Td/

```
.Table .TableHeader td{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
}
.Table .Popup {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Give the parent div the position relative. Then the popup which is a child needs a right: 0px; so that it hugs the right of the parent container.

Comment: any idea why Firefox doesn't like this?

Comment: ahhh because FF doesnt like position:relative on TD or TH. Need to wrap in DIV then it works.

Comment: Nice! Glad you were able to figure that out.

Answer (score 5):

Just add this CSS code:

```
tr.TableHeaderLabels td {
  position: relative;
}

.Table .Popup {
    right: 0;
}
```

I tried it on your jsFiddle and it works as expected :)

EDIT: Forked the original jsFiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/p3khu/1/

Comment: i had to add "position:absolute" to '.Table .Popup' to get it to work in his fiddle

Comment: I tried it on the jsFiddle too and it worked too. Fork the fiddle and provide the working link

Comment: @Ian thanks for the tip, didn't know jsFiddles could be forked ^^' Updatet my answer with the new jsFiddle!

Comment: @mrcasals No problem! Yeah, it's nice because you can start with someone else's fiddle, but not interfere with the edit history :)

Comment: the fiddle worked before. Now it doesnt seem to. Did someone modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are have relative position on the cells containing two, three, four, etc... you can just add `right: 0;` to your css above and that should right align them.

Comment: See my answer: you'll also need the `position: relative;` on the parent `tr` element in order to make it work :)